# Draw a 5 × 5 grid graph. How many edges does the n × n grid graph have?

Tags: graphs, square-grid

just confuse with this problem. What is n × n grid graph and how many edges it has?

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? Let me help with Google toss - [grid graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html). Besides easily found definition it is pure basic math, so this is not the best possible question here.

Comment: @Evil All other faults of the question aside, I think graph theory is firmly ontopic here.

Comment: You should only ask one question per post. Chances are that once you know what a grid graph is you can solve the second question for yourself.

Comment: @Raphael sure, the graph theory certainly is, but counting edges on grid - is it really?

Comment: @Evil It is a combinatorics question but would be part of analysing many a graph algorithm's performance on grid graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a quick google search shows a grid graph to be http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html

so given that a 5 x 5 grid graph would have 25 nodes we can calculate the number of edges using this formula

> A grid graph G_(m,n) has mn nodes and (m-1)n+(n-1)m=2mn-m-n edges

(5-1)5+(5-1)5=2(5)(5)-5-5 = 50 - 10 = 40

the formula itself generalized to nxn is the answer for the second portion

> (n-1)n+(n-1)n=2nn-n-n = 2n^2-2n

Comment: thanks this really helpful.but if this equation is  solve  further then it give zero answer is this correct or not?

Comment: order of operations, you have to resolve the exponent before the subtraction.

Comment: additionally, sanity check your assumptions, there is no way that the general formula can equal zero if n is non 0 -> let nxn = 0, let n = 5,  5x5 grid = 40, 0 != 40

Comment: ok thanks alot . My problem is solved !

Comment: Where does this formula come from? Why is it correct?

Comment: @Raphael Given a M x N matrix, for each row, there are N - 1 edges horizontal edges (N runs from 0 to N - 1), and since there are M rows, there are total M(N - 1) horizontal edges. Similarly, there are N(M - 1) vertical edges. Total number of edges = M(N - 1) + N(M - 1) = 2MN - M - N.

Answer (score 8):

The $a \times b$ grid graph has the vertex set $[a] \times [b]$, and edges of two types: horizontal edges $(i,j),(i+1,j)$ (of which there are $(a-1)b$) and vertical edges $(i,j),(i,j+1)$ (of which there are $a(b-1)$), for a total of $ab$ vertices and $(a-1)b+a(b-1)=2ab-a-b$ edges.

Answer (score 1):

Start by counting the left edges and top edges, then add in the missing right and bottom edges.

For a $m \times n$ grid graph, there are $m \times n-1$ left edges (a left edge for each column at each row). 
 Similarly, there are $m-1 \times n$ top edges.  At this point, we are still missing the bottom edges for the last row, and the right edges for the last column.  There are $n-1$ remaining right edges, and $m-1$ remaining bottom edges.  Hence, the number of edges of an $m \times n$ grid graph is $|E_{m \times n \text{ grid}}| = m(n-1) + (m-1)n = mn-m+mn-n = 2mn-m-n$.